# Retaining hover effect on click of menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I had created a navigation bar that has a .hover effect. but i want that effect that i have added to stay or add when i use .click and i also want to remove that effect when i click another bar. sorry for confusing :)

my code goes like this

html:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <div class="menubutton">Home</div>
    <div class="menubutton">Dessert</div>
    <div class="menubutton">About Us</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#menubar {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}

.menubutton {
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.active {
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.menubutton').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new class `activeClick` for click event as `active` class will remove on hover out event:-

```
$(function(){
 $('.menubutton').click(function(){    
   $('.menubutton').removeClass('activeClick');
   $(this).addClass('activeClick');
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FLVqS/66/)

Comment: @NoobPenguinDeveloper  always looking for help :)

Comment: dude? do you know how to retain my navigation bar when i click or choose on of my menu buttons? or should i just create another html file to link it on my menu buttons? is there any other way? sorry again for confusing, hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: @NoobPenguinDeveloper i can't understand what you exactly want..can you explain? you mean submenues?

Comment: sorry hahaha. Lets just use facebook as an example, you know that blue bar on the top where search, profile name and home etc. is located? do you know how it works?

Comment: ohh you mean fixed position header like http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/F4BmP/ or like http://www.mvpthemes.com/maxmag/ @NoobPenguinDeveloper ?

Comment: Yes something like that but also when you click the home button, the page will only load but not that blue bar.

Comment: Yea you can use $.ajax for that and pull the response to div element so the page will not refresh

Comment: Oh ok, that seems new for me, ill just research for that one. thank you again and sorry for taking this for too long haha

Comment: Could you also give me a sample syntax of that one? thank you haha

Comment: which language programing you are using i.e php or .net?

Comment: Actually I just finished self studying basic css, html, jquery and maybe next week I'll study on php.

Answer (score 2):

Add a click Handler,

```
$('.menubutton').click(function() {
    $('.menubutton.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66sqf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, just wrote this here in the editor:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.menubutton').on('click', function() {
        $('.menubutton').removeClass('active clicked');
        $(this).addClass('active clicked')
    }).on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.menubutton.active').not('.clicked').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).not('.clicked').removeClass('active')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.menubutton').click(function() {
    $('.menubutton').not(this).removeClass('active')
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66sqf/5/)**

Comment: I tried to use toggle but it just worked for a while and then the effect just worked for a while and be gone, guess i have used the wrong syntax, i'll try to use this one. btw what is the use of .not?

Comment: .not will skip the current element and remove active class from other, so that toggleClass should work fine. If I donot use .not then toggleClass will get false value for current element.